# How do I handle this jQuery ajax reponse

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I receive the following

```
[{"user_id":"1","user_invoice_add1":"Stark Towers","user_invoice_add2":"123 Reginald Street","user_invoice_city":"Newport","user_invoice_state":"New York","user_invoice_country":"US","user_invoice_zip":"321654"}]
```

How do I pick out information from it?

trying **data.user_id** or **data[0].user_id** returns as undefined

**jQuery**

```
$.post('post.php', qString, function (obj) {
console.log(obj);
}
```

Comment: show your code once where data is used

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd have to first convert this string into JSON object by using a jQuery function `var obj = $.parseJSON(data)`. 
It will return you a JSON object that you can access like `obj[0].user_id`

Answer (score 0):

use this:

```
 myObject = jQuery.parseJSON( dataReceived );
```

and then you can access the data as properties of the object

Answer (score 0):

Try like this..

```
$.map(data.d, function (item) {
     alert(item.user_id)                 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

[jquery.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) has a setting called `dataType` this is what your getting response from server as..

> "json": Evaluates the response as JSON and returns a JavaScript object. In jQuery 1.4 the JSON data is parsed in a strict manner; any malformed JSON is rejected and a parse error is thrown.

```
$.ajax({
   ....
   dataType:"json",
   success:function(data){
       alert(data.user_id) //no need to parseJSON...dataType does it 
   };
});
```

Using POST

```
$.post('post.php', qString, function (obj) {
  console.log(obj);
}, "json");
```

or you can use `$.parseJSON(data)` to convert the string as json object